# Magento 2.3 - Delta Migration SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: magento2.3.4, delta-migration

Before a month successfully migrated settings and data, now I want to setup Delta migration for update orders and customer details if i run following command

> php bin/magento migrate:delta
> vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.3/config.xml

I am getting the following error,

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '4799     0-1' for key
> 'CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'

How to solve the issue?

> Note:  If delete Duplicate entry 47990 then a new error will generate
> Duplicate entry 47991 it will keep continuing, my id up to 50036, how
> to solve this issue

Comment: may be same issues for you --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10044296/11908692

Comment: @MohitPatel If delete Duplicate entry 47990 then a new error will generate Duplicate entry 47991 it will keep continuing, my id up to 50036, how to solve this issue?